# how to write a BLOB into a database when PreparedStatement.setBlob() not implemented by JDBC driver

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

After I used the following code to write a BLOB value to a database:

```
    // bb is of type ByteBuffer
    Blob blob = new SerialBlob(bb.array());
    sqlStatement = "UPDATE Words SET Examples=? WHERE Word=\"" + word + "\"";
    // c is of type Connection
    PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
    pstmt.setBlob(1, blob);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    c.commit();
```

I got the following error:

> > java.sql.SQLException: **not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver**

No matter where I downloaded this driver from, my question is whether you know of any **SAFE** method to write a BLOB value to a SQLite database.

Comment: where are you setting the value for Example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set value for `Example` column

```
st.setAsciiStream(1, fin, (int) file.length());//if you are storing file in database
```

Comment: its a good practice to use setAsciiStream() or setBinaryStream() instead of setBlob()

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a useful way. Finally I used the following code and it worked!

```
pstmt.setBytes(1, blob.getBytes(1, bb.capacity()));
```